# Rules for special characters in github repository name?

Tags: github, repository

In addition to `-` and `_`, which other special characters can be contained in a github repository name?

#### Background

I need to do some regex on github urls, and need to know the rules for repository root urls, which are of the form

```
https://github.com/username/repo
```

where

- `username` is the username of the owner of the repository, and,
- `repo` is the repository name

So far, my regex works well, but doesn't cater to repositories with special characters, so I must include them. Written in R, the regex is `github.com/*/[[:alpha:]]`.

Note: Here are listed the [rules for github usernames](https://github.com/shinnn/github-username-regex) - I am after the same thing but for repository names

Answer (score 29, accepted):

2019: As mentioned in [`moby/moby` issue 679](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/679#issuecomment-18307522):

> it looks like github allows [A-Za-z0-9_.-], and transforms all other
> characters to "-".

So: in addition to letters, numbers, `-` and `_` the only other allowable character is '`.`'

This is illustrated in GitHub Desktop application, with [desktop/desktop issue 3090](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3090): "Block emoji from being entered as a repo name"(!)

---

2023: [Qunatized](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14923024/qunatized) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081778/rules-for-special-characters-in-github-repository-name/59082561#comment135091370_59082561):

> I just checked on GitHub and was able to create repositories that:
>
> 1. start with "`.`" or "`_`",
> 2. end with "`.`" or "`_`",
> 3. contain an arbitrary number of consecutive "`.`" or "`_`" characters, or any combination thereof.
>
> It only converts any characters outside of [A-Za-z0-9_.-] to "`-`".

I checked, and a repository name can also start or end with '`-`', in addition of '`.`' and '`_`'.

So the current regexp (June 2023) for valid GitHub repository name would be:

```
^[\w-\.]+$
```

Comment: So `[\w.-]+` matches usernames and repos. Thus, for example, something like `match(/github\.com\/([\w.-]+)\/([\w.-]+)/)` would allow extracting username and repo in captured groups.

Comment: @payne Thank you for this interesting feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Repos can also include underscores, though - so this wouldn't work for everything! and usernames can't contain dots.

Edit: oops. I didn't realise what \w did quite.. probably best to remove '.' from the username though

Comment: @TheKodeToad 3+ years later, I find those regexes a bit too simple to accurately match GitHub valid repository names or GitHub usernames. I have edited the answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I saw an npm package for username regex but this seems simpler

Comment: @VonC I just checked on GitHub and was able to create repositories that 1) start with "." or "\_", 2) end with "." or "\_", and 3) contain an arbitrary number of consecutive "." or "\_" characters, or any combination thereof. It only converts any characters outside of [A-Za-z0-9_.-] to "-". Am I missing something? Otherwise the regex should be "^[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+$".

Comment: @Qunatized Interesting. So the naming policy would have evolved?

Comment: @VonC I'm not sure how it was before and unfortunately I couldn't find any official documentation. But I just tested it today and it seems to work. Maybe you could also verify and then update your answer?

Comment: @Qunatized I checked, and the new regexp should now be `^[\w-\.]+$` indeed. I will edit the answer... as soon as I can, since [I can no longer edit answers at the moment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425430/6309). Thank you again for your feedback.

Comment: @Qunatized I ([finally!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message)) managed to update the answer, including your feedback. Thank you for your patience.