# GitHub CLI: Brackets Being Automatically Replaced with Dashes in Repository Name

Tags: github, github-cli

I'm using the GitHub CLI to help me script the migration of a number of repositories from Azure DevOps to GitHib. The repository naming convention that has been used in Azure DevOps is: `BusinessArea.ApplicationName.(InternalApplicationId)`.

e.g.
`CallCentre.TeamManager.(101)`
`Shipping.AddressLabelPrinter.(102)`
`Accounts.InvoiceGenerator.(103)`

However, when I make the following CLI call:
`gh repo create 'company_name/Accounts.InvoiceGenerator.(103)' --private --team=MyTeam`

What actually gets created in GitHub is a repository named:
`company_name/Accounts.InvoiceGenerator.-103-`

Is where a way to force GitHub to respect the brackets and not replace them? It appears to do the same square brackets and I'm imagining other special characters too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe GitHub permits brackets in repository names, if you try and create such a repository manually then GitHub pops up a tooltip showing that it will actually name the repository with the brackets replaced with `-` characters as in your question:

[image: GitHub Auto-renaming images]

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082561/107591) on SO seem to suggest that the names are restricted to `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]`

Comment: I did wonder if it might just be impossible, thanks for clarifying!